# How to show a top level route in Angular named outlet

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Trivial program below with Angular 12:

- localhost:4200/a works fine.
- localhost:4200/b gives me the dreaded **Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'b'**.

```js
import { Component, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ng-container>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <hr/>
      <router-outlet name="named"></router-outlet>  
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'a',
  template: 'a here',
})
export class AComponent {}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'b',
  template: 'b here',
})
export class BComponent {}
```

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    component: AComponent,
    path: 'a'
  },
  {
    component: BComponent,
    path: 'b',
    outlet: 'named'
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, AComponent, BComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Worst case, I can push route 'b' down one level (that didn't work either) but I would prefer to keep b at the top level.

Comment: Did you import BComponent in routing module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow @jay :).

You can check here more info [https://angular.io/](https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial-toh#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets)

when you access route B you need to access with router name as its named route. you can use something like `localhost:4200/a(named:b)`